# Calling a Javascript function from ASP.NET code-behind that is not inline JS

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I've found many examples of people calling inline JS functions that are in their HTML pages, but I'm wondering if it is possible to call JS functions that are in their own file.

For example if we have ~/Scripts/mainjs.js where we house most of our Javascript functions, is there any way to call functions in that file from the C# code-behind?

Edit: Also preferably passing parameters to the JS function

Comment: Your C# code runs on your **server**, while the JavaScript code runs in the client browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
string jsFunc = string.Format("myfunction('{0}');", parameterValue);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "myJsFn", jsFunc, true);
```

Write this in your aspx.cs file
Here myfunction is the Function name and parameterValue are the argument.

Answer (score 0):

The below way may help you if you are using ASP.Net application:

1. include the script file in aspx page
2. create a javascript function on the same aspx page which will call the function from js file
3. Use the newly created function in your c# code behind file

I know it is lengthy but may resolve your problem.

Comment: Ah I was thinking something like this.. just make an inline function in my HTML page that I will use to pass params/call the function I actually need inside my JS file.

I think that is what you mean